# How to force extra dimensions on MultiLineString geometry type?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry-conversion

I attempted to use ST_Force4D() I've used for MultiPolygons (and other geometry), but it doesn't seem to be the correct function. 
`INSERT INTO table_one (geom) SELECT ST_Force4D(geom) FROM table_two;`

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********
ERROR: function st_force4d(geometry) does not exist
```

**How can I force geometry of type MultiLineString to type MultiLineStringZM?**

Comment: Please don't shout. Can you show the context of how you're using that function and why 4D isn't implemented on the lines.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson apologies for the volume, see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PostGIS 2.0 or earlier, use `ST_Force_4D(geom)`.

The function was renamed to `ST_Force4D(geom)` for PostGIS 2.1 and later.